# SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to migrate on my server on goddady but when i try to migrate, i get this error below.

I have already created my database and added a user to the database already with the right credentials.  What could be wrong elsewhere?

> SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'table'@'ip-444-444-444-41.ip.secureserver.net' (using password: YES)

**ENV**

```
DB_HOST=example.com
DB_DATABASE=db
DB_USERNAME=table
DB_PASSWORD=password
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
```

Comment: Can you try 
`php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Either you didn't create the right grants, or you're not using the correct password. What does `SHOW GRANTS FOR table@ip-444-444-444-41.ip.secureserver.net` show?

Comment: @Barmar yes i have assigned all privileges  to the user when i added the user